# How to get DCOM application information using C#

Tags: c#, impersonation, dcom

In my application I need to find the DCOM application information i.e capture DCOM application's Security for

- Launch and activation permissions
- Access Permissions
- Configuration Permissions

How this can be done using C#.

I tried it through many ways

```
using COMAdmin;



        COMAdminCatalog catalog;
        COMAdminCatalogCollection applications;

        // Get the catalog
        catalog = new COMAdminCatalog();

        // Get the list of all COM+ applications contained within this catalog
        applications = (COMAdminCatalogCollection)catalog.GetCollection("Applications");
        applications.Populate();

        foreach (COMAdminCatalogObject application in applications)
        {
            COMAdminCatalogCollection components;
            components = (COMAdminCatalogCollection)applications.GetCollection("Components", application.Key);
            components.Populate();

            foreach (COMAdminCatalogObject component in components)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Component: " + component.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Component: " + component.Valid);
                Console.WriteLine("Component: " + component.Key);

            }
        }
```